# Location of webpack config file in vue-cli webpack project?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I used cli to create a vue.js project. I used the webpack template for it. I have been working on it for a few days and it working smoothly.

Now I need to add a npm package to the project. This package recommends I make some changes to webpack config. But there is not webpack.config.js file at the root of my project. Where is the webpack config file. Do i need to run a command to publish it like in some frameworks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `webpack-simple` template has the `webpack-config.js` file directly in root of your project folder.

Looks like you are using `webpack` template. To make changes to the webpack config goto the **build** folder.

There you will find 3 files related to the webpack config;

1. webpack.base.conf.js
2. webpack.dev.conf.js
3. webpack.prod.conf.js

You can make the change your package requires in the `webpack.base.conf.js` file or in `webpack.dev.conf.js` if the change is for development time config or in `webpack.prod.conf.js` if its for production build config

Comment: Wouldn't this be rewritten every time we run npm build?

Comment: @Anoop.P.A nope they will not be rewritten...they are static config files

Comment: @Vasmi, thanks! but I don't have the file in the project. It seems vue-cli-3 is keeping it somewhere else

Comment: vue cli 3 uses a dynamic approach of creating the webpack config file at runtime. So if you want to tweak the webpack config in a project created by vue cli 3 , you shall use the `vue.config.js` file

Comment: vue cli 4 (@vue/cli@4.3.1) does not seem to have a webpack file as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 24):

If you create your project with the new vue-cli 3 (@vue/cli) will have a file called **vue.config.js** in your project root directory. It means that you can customize your Webpack custom settings just changing the **vue.config.js**, which is automatically included in your project root directory, as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    // It will be merged into the final Webpack config
    plugins: [
      ... // Your plugins here...
    ]
  }
}
```

So easy! Long life to the new vue-cli approach!

Comment: If you don't see vue.config.js in your root it's because it's an optional file.  If you don't have it you can just go ahead and create it.